# Using Copy and Paste in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

It might sound like a trivial question but I found no solution till now..

I am copying some text from powerpoint and pasting it in notepad++

all the text appears as a asingle line with no enter (\n)

I tried find and replace and chose a language but still with that problem

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Well the most likely explanation is the the original text contained no new line characters. Many word processing programs simply wrap text at the margins without any explicit \n characters so if the margins or document size changes they can reformat the text appropriately.

Comment: Try go to "View"->"Show Symbol"->"Show All Characters". If you see some other symbol instead [CR][LF} you can try to replace it on "\n"

Answer (score 0):

The source text does not have line breaks because the source app wrapps the text. You can verify this by pasting into notpad (not notpad++) or any other text editor.
The only option is to enable Word Wrap in notepad++

If you think this is not the case you might enable Show all Characters from the view menu. But I doubt you'll see any CR or LF charcters!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is a MessageBox window that is hidden behind NotePad++, when you close this dialog Copy/Paste will start working again.